# how to Fix Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7

Tags: java, mysql, maven, google-app-engine

I added the dependency for mysql in pom file

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then i start getting the error  given below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: com/mysql/cj/api/CacheAdapter.class in /home/claritus/Downloads/appengine-endpoints-helloworld-java-maven-master/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar
```

Unable to update app: `Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: com/mysql/cj/api/CacheAdapter.class in /home/claritus/Downloads/appengine-endpoints-helloworld-java-maven-master/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar`

I  know java 8 is not supported by the google app engine till now.  so i changed my jdk and  jre path to  java 7. but still i am getting this error at the time of deploying the  code on google app engine.

Comment: did you find any solution related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add mysql driver, it's already provided by App Engine. Specify it as `provided` in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your pom.xml must have:

```
<build>
    <finalName>spring_multilanguage</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>version
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Where is the position of `<build>` pair tags, see an example of `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.vyhn.demo_spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>multilanguage</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>multilanguage Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Do Nhu Vy</name>
            <email>donhuvy@hotmail.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring_multilanguage</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>version
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Google App support Java 8 (in beta): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only