# spring annotation based configuration of appengine-web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine

I want to convert my spring and hibernate based project into gce project.
but don't know how to convert appengine-web.xml into annotation.
Didn't find any source with annotation based configuration.

i tried to add xml in project but it throws an error:

```
Unable to stage:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7  com/mysql/cj/api/CacheAdapter.class
```

i checked and found similar problem:

[how to Fix Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287373/how-to-fix-class-file-is-java-8-but-max-supported-is-java-7)

but solution over there is not able to solve my issue.

then i changed project configuration into java 7 but problem remains same.

Comment: Check compiler version of Projec, rt click project -> properties->project facets.. if compiler 8 is selected change it 7 and it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google app engine by default supports java 7. Add `<vm>true</vm>` into your appengine-web.xml and use flexible environment to work with java 8.

### appengine-web.xml

```
<!-- [START config] -->
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>xxxxxxxxxxxx</application>
  <vm>true</vm>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://connectionName:instanceName/DBName?user=USER&amp;password=PASSWORD;" />
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
<!-- [END config] -->
```